# mocha in watch mode runs the suite twice

Tags: windows, mocha.js

When I run mocha in watch mode, and I save a file, I often see that mocha shortly flashes "1 passing", before giving the correct result.

In the mocha logs, I could see that it started an initial run, aborted, and then restarted.

To further diagnose the problem, I made a small node.js script, that uses `fs.watch` to log file system events. This revealed that when I save a file, 3 or 4 filesystem events are emitted. I assume that this is the cause for the behavior, as the 2nd event is received after mocha started running the test suite.

My initial thoughts was that this was an issue with Windows Defender. But placing the source code under a folder which is excluded from Windows Defender didn't seem to solve the problem (the actual configuration is outside my control, it's a company managed Windows installation). There doesn't seem to be other anti-virus software running.

Why does this happen, and is there any way to fix it, preferably at the source - why does one saved file cause multiple file system events?

And if not fixable, is there a workaround, e.g. make mocha mocha a few milliseconds before running the suite?

I tried creating a 10millisecond delay in a global `before` block, but that just result in "0 passing" instead of "1 passing".

I also tried running mocha with the `--delay` option, and placing this small piece of code in suite:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    run();
}, 10);
```

Same result as before, now it just flashes "0 passing" instead of "1 passing"

Edit:

If I use the "touch" tool from ubuntu running in WSL tool to touch a file, I don't observe this behavior. If I use a minimal neovim in the same ubuntu (empty init file), I do observe this behavior.